# Exception during android app is running and force closing

Tags: smartface.io

I am receiving exception in my app which I published on playstore. The exception and stack trace is as below

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsoluteLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
>       at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:834)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>       at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
>       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Please help me this Smartface Developers.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace and relevant code.

Comment: Which version of Smartface do you use? 4.3.0 or 4.4.0?

Comment: @mervebıçakçı I am using 4.3.0 because there is a problem in webview in android that I can' click on buttons that open's my gallery app so I am using 4.3